# Unable to display 2 images (one below another) in android using imageview and relative layout

Tags: android

I'm using relative layout to show 2 images one below another, but it just don't show the images most of times (gives blank but shows some times correctly). Please suggest me something. Thank you in advance.

I'm setting images through this java code:

```
ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image1.setImageResource(m); 
ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
image2.setImageResource(random);.
```

random is just random image from existing ones.

XML I used for that is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:layout_height="220dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
android:layout_weight="2"
/>


<ImageView 
android:layout_height = "220dp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
android:id = "@+id/imageView2"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
android:layout_below = "@+id/imageView1" 
android:layout_weight="2"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is it the random image that doesn't show sometimes? Or is it both? Can you please post your code for `random` and `m`?

Answer (score 0):

Try just use a LinearLayout and removing a bunch of useless attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


<ImageView 
    android:layout_height = "220dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
    android:id = "@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried it, it doesn't display the images everytime.